# Files missing in XCode 4 Project Navigator after archiving

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I'm currently trying to create version 1.1 of a project I created in XCode 4, but after archiving the files do not appear in the Project Navigator. My initial thought was that I had to clone my repository (git) and thus create a new version in which I could see the 
files, but the clone is also missing the files.

I can access the files from the top bar, but that's not really a desirable solution when 
working with a big project. The case is the same for another project that I have archived
so I suspect it is supposed to be a feature of XCode 4.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Never mind! A friend of mine noticed that somehow the word "main" had appeared in the searchbar below the Project navigator, filtering all files except main.m and MainWindow.xib

Comment: Mine was "Show Only Recent Files".  I didn't even know about that filter thing and I've been using Xcode 4 for months.

Comment: Note that the filter buttons in the bottom are toggles.  Not readily apparent!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(I'm just combining your "nevermind, I found it" comments into an answer, to maintain the SO style, so this question doesn't pop up as needing an answer.)

- Check that you're not filtering file names (left column, bottom.)
- Also make sure you haven't pressed one of the "show only files with..." toggle buttons (same location, near the search entry.)

  - Note that these buttons are *toggles*

Comment: I once look at the filtering text box (left column, bottom) and I see no text, I ignore it and keep searching other places. Eventually I came back and click the filtering text box again. Found out that I must be mis-entering a lot of blank spaces into the filtering text box. ~_~

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  I had to hit the X button with the icon that was blue at the bottom.  This corrected my issue for XCODE Version 6.1.  Thanks.